# Api Call Ajax n seconds GET request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

The API shows live values and changes very frequently, so I am trying to make a call every second and show it to the webpage.

I tried a get request call every N seconds using `set_interval()` but the values load only once and don't make a call again.

```
<p id="val"></p>
<p id="val2"></p>
<p id="val3"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http_url_link", true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = myFunction(xhttp);

function myFunction() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
        var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
        var val1= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_1')[0].childNodes[0];
        var val2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_2')[0].childNodes[0];
        var val3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_3')[0].childNodes[0];
        document.getElementById('val3').innerHTML =
        v3.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById('val').innerHTML =
        v1.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById('val2').innerHTML =
        v2.nodeValue;
    }
}
myFunction();
setInterval(myFunction, (1000));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

here xhttp object create once when the script is running And you get proper output for one time. So you need to call this after 1 second.

```
function myFunction() {
   var xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("GET", "http_url_link", true);
   xhttp.send();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
       var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
       var val1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_1'[0].childNodes[0];
       var val2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_2')[0].childNodes[0];
       var val3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_3')[0].childNodes[0];
       document.getElementById('val3').innerHTML=v3.nodeValue;
       document.getElementById('val').innerHTML=v1.nodeValue;
       document.getElementById('val2').innerHTML=v2.nodeValue;
    }
  }

setInterval(myFunction,(2000));
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: I am now stuck with CORS issue. I seem to get an error 'no access control'. I tried all different solutions out in web. add header() as php, in Javascript. but no luck. Do you know how to sort CORS issue for the same above code?? its weird for one get request it works but for multiple it shows CORS issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    function foo(){ alert("Hello"); }
    setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
    foo();
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to make the API call is outside the function.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http_url_link", true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = myFunctionRes(xhttp);
}
function myFunctionRes()
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
        var val1= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_1')[0].childNodes[0];
        var val2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_2')[0].childNodes[0];
        var val3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('value_3')[0].childNodes[0];
        document.getElementById('val3').innerHTML =
        v3.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById('val').innerHTML =
        v1.nodeValue;
        document.getElementById('val2').innerHTML =
        v2.nodeValue;
    }
}
setInterval(myFunction, (1000));
```

Comment: If I put those 4 lines inside the function, It just crashes my browser. Its get over-loaded. I dont know how to overcome this :/

Comment: That's because setInterval keeps on executing continuously after specified time.
What you should do, using setTimeout make another API call when the first API call finishes and the response in processed.

Comment: What about callbacks? (please don't let the javascript gods kill me for saying that)

Comment: Do something like this: 
setTimeout(function doSomething() {
    console.log("10 seconds");
    setTimeout(doSomething, 10000);
}, 10000);

Comment: I tried setTimeout too. just replaced it from setInterval. still crashes and says : xmlHttprequest cannot load, Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES  and Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded